# Can't read file from my external hard disk on ubuntu

Tags: hardware

I'm in a big problem what happen is when I `mount` my external hard disk on Ubuntu. I can't see any file available on my hard disk, which i can see from windows. 
I tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>  to see if its hidden but it shows no thing. i even tried `ls -a` but the command says input/output error.
And this all seems to happen because  of shortcut virus so i tried `attrb -h -s -r /s /d h:\*.*` in windows and i was able to see the content in windows but can't see them on linux.

Comment: What's your output for `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`? Do you see the drive there? Is a mountpoint listed for the driver? What file system (FSTYPE) does it list for the drive?

Comment: Okay, so the drive you're trying to access is the NTFS partition on sdb1? What is the output for `ls -ha /media/prantik/Surendra`?

Comment: @prantikpok: Was the device disconnected since it was mounted? Also please [edit] your question and [format command output as code](/editing-help#code), when you provide new information. It's much better to have everything ready and readable in one place instead of mangled and scattered throughout the comment section.

Answer (score 2):

Install GParted and gpart.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted gpart
```

Run GParted (you will need to enter your password as it requires root privilige to run).

Select your external hard disk.

Select <kbd>Device</kbd> then <kbd>Attempt Data Rescue</kbd>

This will attempt to find any files on the disk and open a file browser, from which you can copy them to another hard disk.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? What do you mean "friged"?

Comment: It's not instant. It can take a while. I did this recently and it took over 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a corruption problem with your external hard drive. First install ntfsfix:

`sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`

Then scan your hard drive for errors and attempt to fix them:

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1`

Comment: What was the output? Did it fail to run or fail to resolve the problem?

Comment: Try `umount /dev/sdb1` to unmount the drive. Then `mount /dev/sdb1 /media/prantik/Surendra to mount it again. Are you able to `ls` now?

Answer (score 0):

How did you try to mount the file? Did you try this

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/external
```